# HP LaserJet won't print (16.04 LTS)

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, 16.04, hp

I have a weird problem I cannot trace a cause to.

I successfully install HP LaserJet 1018, through Printers / Add Printer / (recognizes the USB connected printer) / select HP / Select driver / Printer successfully installed and I see it in Printers. It's USB connected. When choosing driver, I try the recommended (HP LaserJet 1018 Foomatic/foo2zjs-z1 (recommended).

However, attempting to print says processing, then completed, but nothing comes out, there's no reaction from the printer.

lpq output:

```
    HP-LaserJet-1018 is ready
    no entries
```

lpc status all says:

```
HP-Deskjet-3520-series:
    printer is on device 'hp' speed -1
    queuing is enabled
    printing is enabled
    no entries
    daemon present
HP-LaserJet-1018:
    printer is on device 'hp' speed -1
    queuing is enabled
    printing is enabled
    no entries
    daemon present
Samsung-SCX-4200-Series:
    printer is on device 'usb' speed -1
    queuing is enabled
    printing is disabled
    no entries
    daemon present
```

the problematic printer is LaserJet 1018. Others are currently not connected, but work fine, either from USB or network.

lpstat -a:

```
HP-Deskjet-3520-series accepting requests since Čet 21 Tra 2016 20:31:21
```

[image]

After processing, I see completed, but there's no printing.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS, problem persists at kernels 4.4.0.22 and 4.5.2, and only this printer.

P.S. Worked fine in 14.04 LTS.

Help?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Run command : `sudo hp-setup -i` and then follow the instruction for installation but first delete the printer that you added.

Comment: On 14.04 I never got it right and was doing a plug-in, then turn off, re-plug-in, turn on dance every time to get the thing working. On 16.04, this worked. +1

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with a different HP printer, I found a glitch in the 3.17 installers that may be your problem. Permissions on the PPD file must include X (chmod 754). The 3.17 installers don't set the permissions correctly, and the result is a printer that works just fine except when you print to it. Retreating to 3.16 didn't fix the problem; I'm guessing because the PPD file is left behind during the 3.17 uninstall and 3.16 "assumes" that its permissions are correct.

In any case, try checking the permissions on your PPD file, or just set them with CHMOD 754.

Comment: Great! I confirm the same happens on Ubuntu 18.04 and hplip 3.18.9. In my case running ```sudo chmod 754 /usr/share/ppd/HP -R``` and adding the printer again solved it.

Comment: To find the location of your PPD file use: `lpstat -l -p`